# Regular expressions in a sql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a database table with a column where every entry is a regular expression. For example, the rows in my table look like this:

table: email_address_templates
email_address:  /*.google.com/
email_address:  /*.reddit.com/
email_address:  /*.ac.uk/

I want to be able to search through this table, and find if a particular string matches one of the regular expressions.

In ruby, it would look like this:

```
EmailAddressTemplate.all.select do |ea|
  ea.match "james@something.else.ac.uk"
end
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do a similar thing in pure mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select email_address
from email_address_templates
where "james@something.else.ac.uk" RLIKE email_address_templates;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can handle [POSIX regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

However, these are pretty limited compared to Ruby's, so you will have to make sure everything is compatible.